# Identify substrings between delimiters with regex

Tags: regex, substring, delimiter, regex-group

#### Background

I want to identify text between a starting and an ending delimiter, but I want to have also the different text in between. You can see this example on [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/7ork7).

#### Current solution

##### Input

Text:

```
"aaa_s_123abc_e_bbbccc_s_456def_e_bbbddd_s_7890_e_wwwddd"
```

Pattern:

```
"/(.*?)(_s_.*?_e_)(.*?)/"
```

##### Result

```
0: aaa_s_123abc_e_
1: aaa
2: _s_123abc_e_
3: 
------------------
0: bbbccc_s_456def_e_
1: bbbccc
2: _s_456def_e_
3: 
------------------
0: bbbddd_s_7890_e_
1: bbbddd
2: _s_7890_e_
3: 
------------------
```

#### Problem

I am missing the string `"wwwddd"` at the end.

#### Question

Why is group 3 empty? How do i get the text after the ending delimiter "*e*"?
Any idea how to update the pattern?

Comment: You use lazy quantifiers (`*?`) that match only as little characters as possible, also 0 characters is valid for the `*` pattern. With my knowledge of regex you would have to split your matching into several steps, I don't see a way to match this into groups with a single regex.

Comment: "*How do i get the text after the ending delimiter "*e*"?*": *How many* do you want to match? All of them, from delimiter to end or just one fragment? What is the language/flavor you are using?

Comment: Your current pattern can be written as `(.*?)(_s_.*?_e_)` because the last part for the third capture group `(.*?)` is non greedy and will be empty. This would for example match an optional 3rd capture group at the end of the string that does not match an underscore `(.*?)(_s_.*?_e_)(?:([^_]+)$)?` https://regex101.com/r/QknJ2A/1 But which results do you expect for your example string? Should there always be a group 3 that should not be empty?

Comment: Many thanks for the ideas. I followed now the idea of cyberbrain and created a two step approach. First with the given pattern above (with the corrections The fourth bird proposed). The second step is with this pattern `/(?:$_e_)(?!.*_e_)(.*)/s`, where I grep the tail of the string.

Comment: @TimK. This pattern `(?:$_e_)` which is the same as `$_e_` will not match anything as you first assert the end of the string with `$` and then try to match `_e_` What it the tool/language that you are using and can you update the question with the expected matches/groups?

Comment: What if an `_s_` is not followed by `_e_`?

Comment: @cyberbrain `.?` is known as the *reluctant* quantifier (not "lazy").

Comment: @Tim is it that you want a _4th_ match of `wwwddd` in addition to the 3 matches you listed in your question?

Comment: @Bohemian well probably there are multiple words in common use, the [perlreref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref#QUANTIFIERS) - Perl Regular Expressions Reference - calls that "Minimal Quantifier" (although just in a table heading, never in that actual combination).

Answer (score 1):

When you put a `*` quantifier, 0 to many, that is qualified with a non-greedy `?`
`X*?` at the end of any regex, it will never match anything because it chooses
the `0` part of `to many`.

However if you have something that it must match right after that, it forces the
`to many` part to be tried.

With that knowledge you can make the last segment `(.*?)` a requirement *only at or near the end of string*. This can be written different ways, I liked this way that just excludes underscores at the end.

```
(.*?)(_s_.*?_e_)((?:[^_]+$)?)
```

https://regex101.com/r/zUJ6Fh/1

Overview

```
( .*? )                       # (1)
( _s_ .*? _e_ )               # (2)
(                             # (3 start)
   (?:                           # Cluster an optional segment
      [^_]+                         # that excludes underscore
      $                             # up to the end of string
   )?                            # Optional characters at end of string only
)                             # (3 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why is group 3 empty?

Because the empty string is a match for it, and there is no pattern to match *after* that group, so the empty string suffices to have the regex succeed. Be aware that `?` is lazy. If you would have dropped that last `?`, making the `.*` greedy, the third group would contain all remaining characters in that line. Also that would not be what you wanted, because then it captures *too much*, even all other `_s_` and `_e_`.

> How do i get the text after the ending delimiter "e"?

By:

- repeating the execution of the regex as many times as there are matches. Your programming language is likely to have a function for such repetition. For instance, PHP has [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php); and
- allowing a match (in capture group 1) to be followed by either `_s_` or by the end of the input (`$`).

> Any idea how to update the pattern?

Drop the third capture group, as you want successive matches to be captured by the first capture group.

Proposed regex:

[`(.*?)(?:_s_.*?_e_|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/PoyIZi/1)